# How to focus first item of listview(using list selector)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tv

I need to focus(not selected) first item in default for Android Tv app. 
I tried below code in my activity where listview defined but not working

```
list_view.setAdapter(new LoadRecordListAdapter(getActivity(),
R.layout.child_load_recordlist, LoadScheduleRecordsList));

list_view.setSelection(0);
list_view.getChildAt(0).requestFocus();
```

I'm using listselector so i cant put below code in my listview adapter.

```
if(position==0){
   listview.requestfocus();
}
```

**So can anyone help me to findout any solution??**

**Solved**

**Thank You Kiya**

Add in java

```
list_view.requestFocus();
```

Just add in xml

```
 android:focusable="true"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: are you using leanback?

Comment: No @MatiasOlocco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your `ListView` in xml

```
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```